# Verifying that this extracts the public key from my address, and not the private key

Tags: polkadot-js

I'm using this code sample from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69016885/2028236) to extract my public key from my Dot address. I just want to verify that this is in fact converting my address to the public key.

```
const { decodeAddress } = require('@polkadot/util-crypto');
const { u8aToHex } = require('@polkadot/util');
const publicKey = decodeAddress('5DSaSznmKRjt9Lvg4478V54UU8kdNyZKSQM8brSiczFR1S1H');
const hexPublicKey = u8aToHex(publicKey);
console.log(hexPublicKey);
```

Comment: It is impossible to extract the Private Key from the Public Key, otherwise it would not be secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this code you mention I guess you have generated already the [Keypair](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/keyring/start/basics#keypair-types) of your account, or you can sign a message using the private key of this account.

You can verify a signed message using your public key or using the address. To verify that you have the correct address you can verify the signature using both methods and see if both are valid.

Code example using Alice testing account:

```
// create Alice based on the development seed
const alice = keyring.addFromUri('//Alice');

// create the message and sign it
const message = stringToU8a('this is our message');
const signature = alice.sign(message);

// verify the message using Alice's address
const { isValid } = signatureVerify(message, signature, alice.address);
// verify the message using Alice's public key
const isValidWithPublicKey = alice.verify(message, signature, alice.publicKey);
```